# Load a file then save without save dialog

Tags: c#

```
Stream scriptelfen;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if((scriptelfen = openFileDialog1.OpenFile())!= null)
                {
                string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string filetext = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
                script_box.Text = filetext;
```

When I opened my file, it is displaying text or hex code extension. I want to be able to push save file. I don't have to do a save file dialog is this possible at all ?

Comment: Yes, just save the file. What specific things do you have problems with?

Comment: The `OpenFileDialog` has nothing to do with loading or saving files. Its only job is to select a file name.

Comment: Is that your full code?

Answer (score 2):

[WriteAllText in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx)

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\file.txt", "your content.");
```